# Считать числа с input(), пока не будет введен 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеются числа на ввод, их может быть от до 1 до 10, необходимо подсчитать сумму введенных данных до определенного условия - когда будет введено число "0"
Понимаю что делается все с помощью цикла While, но застрял с int(input()), т.к. не понятно количество чисел, которые будет введено в консоли

Comment: Что именно непонятно? Экстрасенсов нет, покажите код.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если после каждого введенного числа нажимают Enter, то так:

```
el_sum = 0
a = int(input())
while a != 0:
    el_sum += a
    a = int(input())

print(el_sum)
```

Comment: Забыл что int(input()) можно вставить в итерацию. Только я использовал код без функции sum: 
a = 0
b = int(input())
while b != 0:
    a += b
    b = int(input())
print(a)

Comment: @eod sum - это обычная переменная в данном случае, а функция :)

Comment: `sum` - стандартная функция в python, негоже ее переопределять

Comment: @ВладСивирин поправьте, пожалуйста, название переменной sum, т.к. она действительно путает, а вдобавок и вызовет ошибку, при попытке использовать стандартную функцию sum(...). Переопределение - плохо